# Invoking immediate save for Shield UI ASP.NET Chart

Tags: asp.net, shieldui

I am using Shield UI ASP.NET Charts to show registered (and logged in) users informations regarding their accounts. I went through the documentation, but can't find a solution to the following thing: is it possible to invoke an immediate save once the user clicks on the export icon?
I am enabling the save so:

```
 <ExportOptions AllowExportToImage="true" AllowPrint="false" />
```

Are there any edditional parameters to be set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no additional properties to be set/enabled because it is not possible to invoke an immediate save/export of the chart's image (skipping the filename and location choices).
However you may take use of  the additional tooltips:

```
ExportTooltip="" or/and PrintTooltip=""
```

to provide the users some more information if needed.